# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gelecek_üyeliği_sistemi.action_users, users' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I need to get these data from action_users table I have write a query in Mysql and it works fine
but when I am trying to Convert SQL Statement into Laravel Eloquent i got this error

**i am using laravel 8**

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gelecek_üyeliği_sistemi.action_users,users' doesn't exist (SQL: select `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`, `sum(action_users`.`point)` from `action_users,users` where `users`.`id` = action_users.user_id group by `users`)

**here is my query in mysql and works fine in mysql**

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, SUM(action_users.point) FROM action_users, users WHERE users.id=action_users.user_id group by users.id
```

**here is my same query in the controller**

```
$total = DB::table("action_users,users")
->select("users.name","users.email", "sum(action_users.point)")
->where("users.id", "=","action_users.user_id")
->groupBy("users")
->get();

dd($total);
```

**here is action_users migration**

```
 $table->id();
            $table->unSignedBigInteger('admin_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unSignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unSignedBigInteger('action_id')->unsigned();
           $table->foreign('admin_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('admins');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('users'); 
            $table->foreign('action_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('actions');
            $table->integer('point');
```

Comment: Does your table name really have comma in it? I suggest, if possible, to rename the table to something without comma. I think that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query must be changed using join and you must remove users in the first line of query:

```
$total = DB::table("action_users")
   ->join("users","users.id","action_users.user_id")
   ->select("users.name","users.email", "sum(action_users.point)")
   ->where("users.id", "=","action_users.user_id")
   ->groupBy("users.id")
   ->get();
```

Comment: i got this error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(action_users.point)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`, `sum(action_users`.`point)` from `action_users` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `action_users`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = action_users.user_id group by `users`.`id`)

Comment: instead of "sum(action_users.point)" use this
DB::raw("sum(action_users.point)")

Comment: do not forget to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` on top of your class;

Comment: new error i got

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'gelecek_üyeliği_sistemi.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`, sum(action_users.point) from `action_users` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `action_users`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = action_users.user_id group by `users`.`id`)

Comment: it is about your mysql configuration:
try this 

`$total = DB::table("action_users")
   ->join("users", "users.id", "action_users.user_id")
   ->select("users.id","users.name","users.email", "sum(action_users.point)")
   ->groupBy("users.id", "users.name","users.email")
   ->get();`

Comment: same error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(action_users.point)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`, `sum(action_users`.`point)` from `action_users` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `action_users`.`user_id` group by `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `users`.`email`)

Comment: do it again for new query:

`instead of "sum(action_users.point)" use this DB::raw("sum(action_users.point)") `

Comment: i have write this as u said 
 $total = DB::table("action_users")
   ->join("users", "users.id", "action_users.user_id")    
   ->select("users.id","users.name","users.email", DB::raw("sum(action_users.point)")
   ->groupBy("users.id", "users.name","users.email")->get();

i got this error i thing it is in groupby line but i couldn't know where
syntax error, unexpected token ";", expecting ")"

Comment: update your answer to check it , it is works thank you